# How to add ios premium sdk of here map in swift

Tags: swift

I have added  ios premium sdk of here map,but got an error 
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/NMAKit.framework/NMAKit
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/FDDB86EF-870F-4099-ABC5-E5A49FEECCD7/DemoHerePremium.app/DemoHerePremium
  Reason: image not found

Comment: Please follow the question guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's a genuine issue. I faced the same problem while doing HereMap SDK.
Please check the image I have uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here Map SDK needs to be added in Embedded Binaries as well.

[image]

Comment: I have a another question.
In  premium sdk some method are  deprecated, how to use use infoBubble in premium sdk .

Comment: Default function will not work for info bubble. Try to contact Heremap  Support team.
If case they don't give solution we can build it by ourself using UIView

Comment: Can you please tell me how to identify which map object is tapped in MapView and get its coordinate form map.